# Asus Zenfone 3 Zoom broken power/volume key - How to boot

Tags: boot, hardware

I got big problem with my phone (ASUS Zenfone 3 Zoom)

I broke the plug that connect the power/ volume cable so I am not able either turn on the phone or turn to safe mode.

Also the USB debugging mode was not enable so I would appreciate very much could you help me to back up the data and turn on the phone.

I appreciate and thank you very much for your help.

I tried with ADB command but the phone did not seem to be recognized
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

plug in your phone.
immediately after plugging in , hold the volume down key until asus splash screen appears.
now connect your phone to pc.
install adb ("sudo apt install adb" is the command in linux).
enter "adb devices" command.check the device is appearing on your terminal.
then give "adb reboot" command.

This worked for my asus phone.Thank you